# Returning a value 2 stack frames up in Python?

Tags: python

Is it possible to have a function return 2 stack frames up in Python, without having a wrapper function or intermediate handling in the middle function?

Minimum Example:

```
def foo():
    bar()
    return 1


def bar():
   return 2  # Want to change this to make foo's return value 2, not 1


foo() # Want this to return 2
```

Of course, this would be possible by modifying `foo`, but I'm wondering if there's a statement in Python to return the value of `2` from `bar` several stack frames up, for example instead of `foo`'s return value of `1`.

I've tried looking into some introspection techniques, but Python doesn't seem to support much.

Maybe this approach should never be taken, because it breaks concepts of encapsulation?

Comment: I upvoted and bookmarked this, I'm curious of the answers...

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if there's a statement in Python to return the value of 2 from bar several stack frames up, for example instead of foo's return value of 1.

There is no such *statement*.  What you describe is certainly *possible* in python, but as a day-to-day programming technique rather than a debugging technique it's completely mental.

> Maybe this approach should never be taken

Yes!  (In python, and language with cheap pass-by-reference everywhere.)  Python isn't a push-n-pop-the-stack language...